# how to set class to viewcontroller programmatically in swift?

Tags: swift, class, storyboard

i have 3 buttons, 3 Classes and 3 Viewcontrollers same UI, only different values.
so i want to do 3 buttons showed 1 Viewcontrollers but used different Classes.

My logic:
when pressing the button > set class > present vc

```
@IBAction func openTest(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExSim")

        // i want to change class here

        present(vc, animated: true)

    }
```

Comment: That’s not really how this works. The class of each object in a Storyboard is baked into the store board itself. Inside the call to `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`, the classes are look up by their name, and new instances are created from them. You can’t change that. From what I gather, you have 3 different classes because you’re trying to make three similar views that differ in some way. There are better ways to express that. What differences are you trying to capture here?

Comment: those are 3 different tests with the same interface. Only the results of the count and the content of the questions are different.

Now I have 3 viewcontrollers, but I think it would be right to optimize into one

Comment: It’s not really an optimization, it’s just practical. Classes are fundamentally for expressing differences in behaviour, but what you’ve described is just one behaviour (showing questions/answers), which only differs by its content. Rather than setting the class on the view controller (if it were hypothetically possible), you would just set some `questions: [Question]` field on each object.

Comment: Approximately that's how it is. I have listQuestions1, listQuestions2 = [Questions]. And i use class1 in VC1 with listQuestions1. Class2 in VC2 with listQuestions2. Class3 in VC3 with listQuestions1+listQuestions2. And now I think that it can be done somehow better, no result so far, but it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a basic misunderstanding. When you add a view controller to a storyboard, you tell the storyboard what subclass of view controller you are adding, and give it a unique identifier. Any time you instantiate a view controller from your storyboard using a specific identifier, you will always get a view controller of the subclass that’s defined in the storyboard. You can’t fetch a view controller from a storyboard and then transform it to a different class.

If you have 3 different screens that have have the same UI but different contents, you should use a model object to describe the contents that view controller displays. Always use the same identifier to instantiate it, and install a different model object into it depending on which button is pressed. Have the view controller load its contents into its views from the model object.

If you don’t know what a model object is, you need to read up on design patterns like MVC and MVVM, and maybe try a few tutorials that create apps using the MVC and MVVM design patterns